# call a function from another function within the class

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

My class is,

```
 class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(self,parent,ID,title):
         wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^   wx.RESIZE_BORDER ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX,size=(600,500))
         wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self) 
         ..........
         ..........
         panel1 = wx.Panel(panel, wx.ID_ANY,size=(550,200),pos=(25,150))
         log = wx.TextCtrl(panel1, wx.ID_ANY, size=(550,200),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)

     def PanelStatus(message):
         ...............
```

I want to call method Panel1 from function '**init**' in the function 'PanelStatus' and later call this function in the other class.How to do that?? I am very new to programming language.Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to give your `PanelStatus` function a new first argument `self`. That's because it's a method, and methods will automatically get the instance they are called on passed as the first argument (the name `self` is a convention).

Then, you can call it from `__init__` with `self.PanelStatus("some message")`. If other code in other parts of your program have a reference to a `MainFrame` instance, they can call `myMainFrame.PanelStatus("some other message")`.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it worked for me.

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,ID,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX,size=(600,500))
        .......
        .......
        panel1 = wx.Panel(panel, wx.ID_ANY,size=(550,200),pos=(25,150))
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(panel1, wx.ID_ANY, size=(550,200),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)


    def PanelStatus(self,message):
        self.log.AppendText(message)
```

and used ***self.PanelStatus("my text")*** in the other function.